# Are closures of products of unimodular subgroups unimodular?

Tags: topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, $N \subset G$ a unimodular normal subgroup, and $H \subset G$ a discrete (hence unimodular) subgroup. Does it follow that the closure $\overline{NH} \subset G$ is unimodular?

Comment: No: take $G=\mathbf{R}\rtimes\mathbf{Z}$ with faithful action. So $G$ is not unimodular (in a sense this is the simplest non-unimodular LC-group one can imagine). Take $N=\mathbf{R}$, $H=\mathbf{Z}$. Maybe the answer is yes iff the $H$-action on $N$ is Haar-measure-preserving.